# Update database with populated Form using Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, validation

I managed to retrieve user's data from database and populate a form for future updates. With my view in place and data loaded on the fields, I have an update button that calls my controller for validation. Apparently, form_validation->run() is returning false.
Below is my view, I do the same for name and last name:

```
//
        //EMAIL
        //
        $data_email= array( 'name' => 'email',
                            'placeholder' => '',
                            'value' => $account->email,
                            'class' => 'span12',
                            'rules' => 'required',
                            'style'=> 'font-size:18px;');
        $email = array('class' => '',
                       'style' => 'font-weight:bold;');

        echo form_label('Email: ','email', $email);             
        echo form_input($data_email);
        //
        //END OF EMAIL
        //
```

Below is my controller

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('fname', 'First Name', 'required|trim|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('lname', 'Last Name', 'required|trim|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email','required|trim|xss_clean|valid_email|is_unique[accounts.email]|is_unique[temp_accounts.email]');
```

at this point form_validation->run() returns an false, unable to validate the data from the form. Any suggestions will be really appreciated.

Comment: Have you narrowed down which rule is failing validation?

Comment: I have not found out which rule is causing it.

Comment: So you didn't think about removing rules one by one to see which field and which rule was causing the validation to fail? That would be the most obvious thing to do before you ask us to help where we will just end up telling you to do the same thing. Please make an effort in debugging first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure since the description isn't very clear, but could you try removing the is_unique rules from the validation rules?

I'm guessing your code is checking if this email is already in the accounts table, and it will be if this view is being populated from your database.

Comment: I thought about that too but how would you propose to evaluate if the email exists if the user updates his email?

Comment: Well, I would do a manual check if this email address already exists in the database instead of the form validator method. Can you try checking if it works without that form validator part?